# Merging (zipping) two arrays of different length with map() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, zip

I am trying to wrap my head around the map() method, in this case using it to combine (zip) two arrays of different lengths. I have checked previous questions regarding zipping in JavaScript but they have mostly concerned arrays of equal length.

I have two arrays:

```
const countries = ['US', 'FR', 'IT']
const area = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]

let merge = countries.map(function (c) {
    area.map(function (a) {
        return c + a
    // This returns an array of length 3 (prints country + all areas into one array position)
    // However if I create a third array and use push(c + a) here instead then length is 21 (which is what I am trying to achieve). 
    })
})
```

Am I returning the wrong values? Like I wrote in the comment, if I print or push (c+a) into another array then I get all 21 possible combinations. The whole point of map() is getting a new array so I would prefer not pushing into a third one. I have also heard that nested forEach loops is bad practice (if I was to go for it anyhow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.map` will necessarily create a new array which is the same length as the array being iterated over. Because `countries` has 3 items, your output will also have 3 items (an array of arrays) if you use `countries.map`.

Using `.map` won't work here, because none of your input arrays are the same length as the desired output array. Either `.push` to an outside variable, like you already know about, or use `.reduce` and push to the accumulator:

```js
const countries = ['US', 'FR', 'IT']
const area = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]

const merged = countries.reduce((merged, c) => {
  area.forEach((a) => {
    merged.push(c + a);
  });
  return merged;
}, []);
console.log(merged);
```

The algorithm to create a 21-length array from arrays of length 7 and 3 will necessarily involve a nested loop - there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

***Your code is fine***, the only thing you need to do `flatten` the array after mapping, as internal map will return an array whereas you want a single array containing all the value, so you just need to flatten the array. [`flat MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const countries = ['US', 'FR', 'IT']
const area = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]

let merge = countries.map(function (c) {
    return area.map(function (a) {
        return c + a
    })
}).flat()

console.log(merge)
```

One more way is to use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const countries = ['US', 'FR', 'IT']
const area = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]

let merge = countries.flatMap((c, i) => area.map(a => c + a))

console.log(merge)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
const countries = ['US', 'FR', 'IT'];
const area = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130];
let merge = countries.map(x => [x, area]);
console.log(merge);
```

and you should get

```
Array [Array ["US", Array [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]], Array ["FR", Array [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]], Array ["IT", Array [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]]]
```